# Whats the difference between new & direct assignment in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Here's my scenario:

```
> var babloo = new Number(12)

[Number: 12]

> var bablaa = 12

12

> babloo.

babloo.__defineGetter__      babloo.__defineSetter__      babloo.__lookupGetter__      babloo.__lookupSetter__      babloo.__proto__             babloo.constructor           babloo.hasOwnProperty
babloo.isPrototypeOf         babloo.propertyIsEnumerable  babloo.toLocaleString        babloo.toString              babloo.valueOf               
babloo.toExponential         babloo.toFixed               babloo.toPrecision           

> bablaa.

bablaa.__defineGetter__      bablaa.__defineSetter__      bablaa.__lookupGetter__      bablaa.__lookupSetter__      bablaa.__proto__             bablaa.constructor           bablaa.hasOwnProperty
bablaa.isPrototypeOf         bablaa.propertyIsEnumerable  bablaa.toLocaleString        bablaa.toString              bablaa.valueOf               
bablaa.toExponential         bablaa.toFixed               bablaa.toPrecision           

> typeof babloo

'object'
> typeof bablaa

'number'
```

What's the difference between the "babloo" and "bablaa" here? Is there a scenario where their usages need to be handled differently?

Answer (score 1):

consider :

```
var babloo = new Number(12);   //typeof babloo is "object"
```

It is created using `Number constructor` explicitly whose `PrimitiveValue` propertie is set to 12

consider :

```
var bablaa = 12    //typeof bablaa is "number"
```

Its holding primitive datatype number having value 12.

Its also constructed using `Number constructor` but implicitly using `Number` as a wrapper .

If call

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(babloo)  //Number
```

and

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(bablaa)     //Number
```

both will  return `Number` as its prototpe.